# browser doesn't display the image with canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i wrote this code but the browser refuse to display the pipe image from canvas. I need some help please.

```js
var  cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx =  cvs.getContext("2d");
var chickenImage = new Image();
var pipe = new Image();
var  jumpSound = new Audio();
chickenImage.src="asset/chicken.png";
pipe.src ="asset/pipe.png";
jumpSound.src ="asset/jump.wav";

function draw(){
 ctx.drawImage(pipe,100,0);

}
draw();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>chicken</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="288" height="512"></canvas>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get some errors in the console? Try to inspect the DOM elements and see what is there. And maybe you will need to wait for `load` event of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wait for `onload` event, for the image to be loaded then you can draw her in the canvas.

```
pipe.onload = function () {
  ctx.drawImage(pipe, 0, 0);
};
pipe.src ="asset/pipe.png";
```

Or in your code you can use also:

```
pipe.onload = function () {
  draw();
};
pipe.src ="asset/pipe.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the image is loaded. The easiest way would be the `.onload` event which is run, when the image is finished loading and to use it just set it to your `draw()` function.

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
var chickenImage = new Image();
var pipe = new Image();
var jumpSound = new Audio();
//chickenImage.src="asset/chicken.png";
pipe.src = "https://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/?random";
//jumpSound.src ="asset/jump.wav";

function draw() {
  ctx.drawImage(pipe, 100, 0);

}

pipe.onload = draw;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>chicken</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="288" height="512"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```